# JavaScript errors after changing HTML file directory

Tags: javascript, html

Having javascript errors after changing the directories of html files. In inspect mode each time when I scroll the page javascript errors keep increasing kindly help me out with this issue. Also have changed the javascript files directory. I am sharing an image of errors.

[Directory of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aebOn.jpg)

Here is the part which is having errors in Total.min.js

```
function e(y) {
        var b, w, x, $ = !1;

        function S(t, e) {
            if (C.getComputedStyle || -1 === e.indexOf("%")) return e;
            var i = t.style,
                s = i.left,
                n = t.runtimeStyle,
                o = n && n.left;
            return o && (n.left = t.currentStyle.left), i.left = e, e = i.pixelLeft, i.left = s, o && (n.left = o), e
        }
        return function(t) {
            if (function() {
                    if (!$) {
                        $ = !0;
                        var i, e = C.getComputedStyle;
                        if (i = e ? function(t) {
                                return e(t, null)
                            } : function(t) {
                                return t.currentStyle
                            }, b = function(t) {
                                var e = i(t);
                                return e || T("Style returned " + e + "."), e
                            }, w = y("boxSizing")) {
                            var t = document.createElement("div");
                            t.style.width = "200px", t.style.padding = "1px 2px 3px 4px", t.style.borderStyle = "solid", t.style.borderWidth = "1px 2px 3px 4px", t.style[w] = "border-box";
                            var s = document.body || document.documentElement;
                            s.appendChild(t);
                            var n = b(t);
                            x = 200 === _(n.width), s.removeChild(t)
                        }
                    }
                }(), "string" == typeof t && (t = document.querySelector(t)), t && "object" == typeof t && t.nodeType) {
                var e = b(t);
                if ("none" === e.display) return function() {
                    for (var t = {
                            width: 0,
                            height: 0,
                            innerWidth: 0,
                            innerHeight: 0,
                            outerWidth: 0,
                            outerHeight: 0
                        }, e = 0, i = I.length; e < i; e++) t[I[e]] = 0;
                    return t
                }();
                var i = {};
                i.width = t.offsetWidth, i.height = t.offsetHeight;
                for (var s = i.isBorderBox = !(!w || !e[w] || "border-box" !== e[w]), n = 0, o = I.length; n < o; n++) {
                    var a = I[n],
                        r = e[a];
                    r = S(t, r);
                    var l = parseFloat(r);
                    i[a] = isNaN(l) ? 0 : l
                }
                var h = i.paddingLeft + i.paddingRight,
                    c = i.paddingTop + i.paddingBottom,
                    d = i.marginLeft + i.marginRight,
                    u = i.marginTop + i.marginBottom,
                    p = i.borderLeftWidth + i.borderRightWidth,
                    f = i.borderTopWidth + i.borderBottomWidth,
                    m = s && x,
                    g = _(e.width);
                !1 !== g && (i.width = g + (m ? 0 : h + p));
                var v = _(e.height);
                return !1 !== v && (i.height = v + (m ? 0 : c + f)), i.innerWidth = i.width - (h + p), i.innerHeight = i.height - (c + f), i.outerWidth = i.width + d, i.outerHeight = i.height + u, i
            }
        }
    }
    "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define("get-size/get-size", ["get-style-property/get-style-property"], e) : "object" == typeof exports ? module.exports = e(require("desandro-get-style-property")) : C.getSize = e(C.getStyleProperty)
}(window),
function(e) {
    var i = e.document,
        s = [];

    function n(t) {
        "function" == typeof t && (n.isReady ? t() : s.push(t))
    }

    function o(t) {
        var e = "readystatechange" === t.type && "complete" !== i.readyState;
        n.isReady || e || a()
    }

    function a() {
        n.isReady = !0;
        for (var t = 0, e = s.length; t < e; t++) {
            (0, s[t])()
        }
    }

    function t(t) {
        return "complete" === i.readyState ? a() : (t.bind(i, "DOMContentLoaded", o), t.bind(i, "readystatechange", o), t.bind(e, "load", o)), n
    }
    n.isReady = !1, "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define("doc-ready/doc-ready", ["eventie/eventie"], t) : "object" == typeof exports ? module.exports = t(require("eventie")) : e.docReady = t(e.eventie)
}(window),
function(n) {
    "use strict";
    var t, i = function() {
        if (n.matches) return "matches";
        if (n.matchesSelector) return "matchesSelector";
        for (var t = ["webkit", "moz", "ms", "o"], e = 0, i = t.length; e < i; e++) {
            var s = t[e] + "MatchesSelector";
            if (n[s]) return s
        }
    }();
```

[Errors during inspecting site in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMWAw.jpg)

Comment: Please change the js files paths too.

Comment: yes I did but its still same

Comment: Please add your code so we can see where the problem might be.

Comment: Can you share the code and dir structure?

Comment: have added the code  kindly check thanks !!